# PHPMailer issue: no new line in message body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Interesting issue with PHPMailer.

I tried sending an email as this:

`$mail->Body    = "hello, world.";`

`$mail->isHTML(false);`

`$mail->send();`

The body turned out to be empty when i received the message in gmail. When i inspected the body source i found this.

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"Hello, world.

So then i did this:

`$mail->Body    = "\n\nhello, world.";         <------`

`$mail->isHTML(false);`

`$mail->send();`

And that solved the issue:

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

Hello, world.

But this can't be right. So what am i doing wrong for PHPMailer not adding a linefeed by default?

Comment: It might be the `AltBody` is correct instead of `Body`. There are plenty of examples to be found https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/

Comment: All my headers have \n\ at end, I don't understand why is that problem? You have to detach body from headers...